# document type does not allow element "STYLE" here

Tags: html, doctype

I am currently using this DOCTYPE: `<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>`

However, when I validate my web page, I am getting the following error:

> document type does not allow element "STYLE" here, at `<style
>   type="text/css">`

Can you please advise me on the correct `DOCTYPE` that I should use?

Thanks

Comment: Where have you placed the `<style>` element? Why do you have `SYSTEM` in the DOCTYPE declaration?

Comment: @Oded If you use the W3C validator on a html file without a DOCTYPE, the validator suggests this.

Comment: @MrLister - Never having done so means I didn't know that ;)

Comment: The validator says that `<DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>` is a fallback doctype that maps to a 'Document Type Definition that closely resembles “HTML 4.01 Transitional”'. It says what it uses as a DTD in the absence of a DOCTYPE; it does not actually suggest authors should use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints :**

- Put your script and style tags, in your HEAD section
- Put the rest in your BODY section
- Remember to "close" all tags.

---

```
<html>
      <head>
             <!-- title,scripts & styles go here -->
      </head>
      <body>
             <!-- the rest goes here -->
      </body>
</html>
```

**Your Code : (UPDATED : Passes validation)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>World Flag Registration</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            label{
                display:inline-block;
                width:200px;
                margin-right:30px;
                text-align:right;
            }

            input{

            }

            a, a:link, a:visited, a:active { 
                 color: #000000;
            }

            fieldset{
                border:none;
                width:500px;
                margin:0px auto;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <form onsubmit="return validate(this);" action="registrationSubmit.html">
            <p align="center"><font face="Times New Roman" size="6">World Flag Registration</font></p>
            <p align="center"><a href="index.html"><font face="Times New Roman">Home</font></a> | <a href="registration.html"> Register</a> | Play</p>
            <p align="center">Please register your school in order to play the Flag Quiz</p>

            <fieldset>
                <legend></legend>
                <label>Classroom name:</label><input type="text" name="txtClassroomName" size="20">
                <label>School name:</label><input type="text" name="txtSchoolName" size="20">
                <label>School contact email address:</label><input type="text" name="txtSchoolEmail" size="20">
                <label>School address:</label><input type="text" name="txtSchoolAddress" size="20">
                <label>School telephone number:</label><input type="text" name="txtTelephoneNumber" size="20">
            </fieldset>

            <div style="text-align:center">
                <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onClick="Submit" align="middle">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Dr.Kameleon. I tried to validate this page, and I am getting a lot of errors that I did not have before... many saying Use CSS instead. Before the change, I had only 1 error.. Any advice?

Comment: @user1309887 Go here (http://validator.w3.org/check) and check it out. I've re-updated my initial code. Now, it's validating 100%. ;-)

Comment: Awesome. Just one thing, I am wanting to add the following code: <body link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000">. How can I do this, and still get it to validate?

Comment: @user1309887 Add a tiny extra section in the style (`a, a:link, a:visited, etc...`). Add this, and it'll be fine. It still validates. ;-)

Comment: Thanks heaps Dr.Kameleon. Works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply delete that `SYSTEM` :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

or, perhaps :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

And try to see if it works...

Comment: I tried both of those... and then I get a lot of errors via the validator that were not there before the SYSTEM doctype. Here is a link to my page if it will help: http://www.canning.co.nz/Game/registration.html

Comment: @user1309887 Just put a `</HEAD>` tag, immediately after your `</STYLE>` TAG ;-) (and the `<body...` tag AFTER your `</HEAD>` tag).

Comment: @user1309887 Have a look at my other Answer please.

Comment: @user1309887 If you _read_ those error messages, it should become clear what to do about them!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't depend on what DOCTYPE declaration you have, or even if you have one or not.
Your `<style>` element is in the wrong place in your document. Move it up into the `<head>`.

To clarify, if the W3C validator says "document type", it simply means the kind of document, i.e. HTML. And that is *not* the same as "DOCTYPE declaration", the prolog you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably placed the `style` element inside the `body` element. Though it works OK there, it is not allowed by the formal rules. Move it into the `head` element.

If problems remain, please provide a link to the document as a whole. When the problem is that an element appears in a wrong context, like here, the context is all-important.